# Show records where most recent 'x' records meet criteria

Tags: sql-server

Here's a simplified [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afb22/9) example of data

Basically, I'm looking to identify records in a login audit table where the most recent records for each user has 'x' (let's say 3, for this example) number of failed logins

I am able to get this data for individual users by doing a SELECT TOP 3 and ordering by the log date in descending order and evaluating those records, but I know there's got to be a better way to do this.

I have tried a few queries using ROW_NUMBER(), partitioning by UserName and Success and ordering by LogDate, but I can't quite get it to do what I want. Essentially, every time a successful login occurs, I want the failed login counter to be reset.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand question right, can you give expected results? I mean in fiddle bob has 2 failed attempts, but it is wrong, it has 1 success after this, so for my logic it should be 0

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it very. Previously, I was able to identify how many consecutive failed attempts they've had during a certain amount of login attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
select * from (
select distinct a.UserName,
    (select sum(cast(Success as int)) from (
    SELECT TOP 3 Success --- here 3, change it to your number
    FROM tbl as b
    WHERE b.UserName=a.UserName
    ORDER BY LogDate DESC
    ) as q
    having count(*) >= 3 --- this string need to remove users who made less then 3 attempts
    ) as cnts
from tbl as a
) as q2
where q2.cnts=0
```

it shows users with all last 3 attempts failed, with different modifications, you can use this approach to identify how many success/fail attempts where done during last N rows

NOTE: this query works, but it is not the optimal way, `from tbl as a` should be changed to table where only users are stored, so you will be able to get rid of `distinct`, also - store users ID instead of username in tbl

Comment: Right now, I think this gets me close to what I was trying to do. Still feels a bit clunky, but I'm not sure if that is because of the nature of what I'm trying to do or whether it just needs refined a bit. Until you or someone else is able to come up with a more elegant way of getting at the data, I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also, that schema was just a very simplistic version of the data. The real version uses IDs ;)