# SQL where last n records for each id meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql-server

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578294/show-records-where-most-recent-x-records-meet-criteria) was the closest I have found to my problem but it still doesn't solve it.

I have a (simplified) table like:

```
ID  Value   Date
1   CCC     2013-09-06
1   CCC     2015-07-13
1   AAA     2015-10-15
1   AAA     2015-10-29
1   AAA     2015-11-17
1   AAA     2015-12-22
2   AAA     2019-11-01
3   BBB     2017-10-02
3   AAA     2017-12-21
3   AAA     2018-01-18
3   AAA     2018-02-20
3   AAA     2018-03-20
3   AAA     2018-05-16
3   AAA     2018-08-15
3   AAA     2018-11-14
```

I'd like to have the IDs that have the value AAA on the last five entries by date.
In my example, the result would be

```
ID
--
3
```

ID 1 does not meet the criteria because when ordered by date, one of the last four entries are not 'AAA'.

ID 2 does not meet the criteria because although it's last value is AAA, it does not even at least 5 entries (only 1)

I have tried dividing my problem in different steps, first identifiying all IDs that have at least 5 records, with a simple select TOP 5 ordered by date DESC.
I have also succeeded in finding all records that have at least five 'AAA' values, using COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING.

But I have been unable to take into account if those records found are the last five by date.

I appreciate any help/tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirement of last 5 or more records check. If we have continuous rows for 'AAA' and then 'CCC' or anything other, we need to make sure that we are comparing the table to make sure that there is no other values.

```
     with cte as (
select 1 as ID, '2019-02' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-03' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-04' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-01' as Date, 'BBB' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-06' as Date, 'CCC' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-07' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-08' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-09' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-10' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 1 as ID, '2019-11' as Date, 'CCC' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-05' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-07' as Date, 'BBB' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-03' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-08' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-09' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-10' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-11' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 2 as ID, '2019-12' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-02' as Date, 'CCC' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-03' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-02' as Date, 'BBB' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-04' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-05' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-06' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-07' as Date, 'AAA' as Value union all
select 3 as ID, '2019-08' as Date, 'AAA' as Value 
 ) 





    select ID  
 from  cte  z
  where not exists (Select 1 from cte c where z.id = c.id and z.Date < c.Date and c.Value <> 'AAA')
 group by ID  
 having count(case when Value = 'AAA' then 1 end  ) >=5  



Output:
ID 

3
```

Comment: Avii, thanks for your quick answer.. In fact, I really need to find the IDs that have the value AAA on the last FIVE entries by date. 
I thought that by simplifying it to two, my example would be easier to understand

Comment: @msks2007 Thanks for providing information. I have updated the query, and I think this should satisfy for any cases of 5 occurrences or more

Comment: @Avii Thank you again for your interest. Unfortunately, when testing your sql with my real data (about 220k records), I get mixed results.. I do get many correct, but for example, I also find IDs that have only one record (and the record does not even have 'AAA' as value. 
I'll post an example as soon as I can find a reasonably sized subset of the data to be able to reproduce the problem.
As a sidenote, I have to do this in SQLServer 2008R2... I don't really know if that might be the problem.

Comment: @msks2007 SQL server version should not matter ideally .. unless you have some duplicates in the table for the same value and month it should work.. if you could post on scenarios which are not working that would be helpful to make a query .. I am just making query based on the sample you mentioned and provided

Comment: @Avii, I've updated the original question, so I could post a proper example. The one shown there, returns 1 and 3 as a result with your query, but ID 1 does not meet the criteria.

Comment: @msks2007 I think this should work.. added a condition to include only AAA in the aggregation

Comment: @Avii. Works like a charm. Thank you. I only wish I could understand the logic behind the sql, which confuses me a bit.

Comment: @msks2007 that's great to know .. basically it checks if we have any cases with AAA value and date with less than <> AAA and with higher date.. it won't display the data .. count condition will make sure we are evaluating only AAA to make sure minimum consecutive count is 5 or more

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
Select * from
(Select Id,Date,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by Date DESC) As Rw From Temp) T
WHERE T.Rw=1 OR T.Rw=2 
Order By Id
```

Query to assign Rw column and use filter on this column.

Comment: honestly, I was unable to get this to work. I'm probably not understanding your statement about "query to assign Rw column and use filter". I also guess I'm not replacing Temp with the correct statement.
As a sidenote, I guess WHERE T.Rw=1 OR T.Rw=2, would in fact need to be replaced by T.Rw>=1 AND T.Rw<=5 (since I clarified that in fact I had simplified the requirements to be easier to understand, but I really need the last 5 records for each ID to be a certain value)